# Composite functions equal to identity problem

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Find example of functions f,g : N → N (N= {0, 1, 2, . . . }), so that f ◦ g = idN and simultaneously g ◦ f ≠ idN (or justify, why those functions don't exist.)

I'm having problem solving this one. I know this tells us that function *f* is the inverse function of *g*. But let's say we pick some g that is injective but not surjective, for example *g* = 2x, then I can't find an *f* that works. So the part g ◦ f ≠ idN is correct, because I can't compose two functions to be equal to idN. So bottom line is, I can't find any examples of functions f,g.

I may be mistaken so if someone could correct me, I would be more than grateful.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint, if $f\circ g$ is injective, then $g$ is injective. If $f\circ g$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective. So if there is an example, you will need $g$ injective and $f$ surjective.

See what happens when $g(x)=2x$. You can construct a function $f$ which "undoes $g$" by dividing by $2$, but this only works for even numbers. So extend $f$ however you like to get a function $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$.

Comment: Possibly simpler: let $g(x)=x+1$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. If g(x) = x + 1, I can't find an that f: N →N and I don't think I can find an f for any g.

Comment: What do you mean? You can send $x$ to $x-1$ to recover $x$. Send $0$ to $0$ or something.

Comment: My understanding is as follows: f ◦ g = idN means that f is the inverse function of g. If I let g(x) = x + 1, then f(x) = x - 1. So let x = 1, g(f(1) = g(0) = 1 which is correct, but f can't be x-1 because if I let x = 0, then f(0) = -1 and -1 doesn't belong to N= {0, 1, 2, . . . }. One thing that comes to my mind is if I could extend function f so when x = 0, I would choose some a ∈ N. I apologize for my bad formatting.

Comment: "One thing that comes to mind is if I could extend function $f$ so when $x=0$, I would choose some $a$ in $\bf N$." That's *exactly* what Elliot is telling you to do! Also: $f$ is *not* the inverse function of $g$, it is merely the *left* inverse of $g$. This problem is precisely about the difference between inverses and one-sided inverses. Neither $f$ nor $g$ has an inverse, but $f$ is a left inverse of $g$, and $g$ is a right inverse of $f$.

Comment: So if i extend f so that f(x) = \begin{cases}
a,  & \text{if $x$ = 0} \\
x-1, & \text{$x$ ∈ N - {0}}
\end{cases}  and let g(x) = x+1, then these are the examples I'm looking for, right?

Comment: If you specify $a$, then, yes, that's an example. The one Elliot gives, with $g(x)=2x$, is another example. There is no shortage of examples. Elliot has given the general rule for constructing examples.

Comment: If you are satisfied now with Elliot's answer, wizard, you have the option of "accepting" it, by clicking in the check mark next to it.